# Back button and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-tablayout, onbackpressed

I am using viewPager with android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.  My xml is

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/home_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <!-- tabs -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="@color/light_blue_low_opacity"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/light_green"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/HomeTabsTextAppearance"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I set viewPager as below

```
 mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.home_container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_tabs);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.color_home_tabs));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

My tabListener is

```
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        super.onTabSelected(tab);
                        int position = tab.getPosition();
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

                    String tab0TextUnSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab1) + " </font>";
                    String tab1TextUnSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab2) + "</font>";
                    String tab2TextUnSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab3) + "</font>";
                    String tab3TextUnSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab4) + "</font>";
                    String tab4TextUnSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.white) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab5) + "</font>";


                    String tab0TextSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.light_green) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab1) + " </font>";
                    String tab1TextSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.light_green) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab2) + "</font>";
                    String tab2TextSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.light_green) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab3) + "</font>";
                    String tab3TextSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.light_green) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab4) + "</font>";
                    String tab4TextSelected = "<font color='" + ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.light_green) + "'> " + getResources().getString(R.string.home_tab5) + "</font>";

                    TabLayout.Tab tab0 = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
                    TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
                    TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
                    TabLayout.Tab tab3 = tabLayout.getTabAt(3);
                    TabLayout.Tab tab4 = tabLayout.getTabAt(4);


                    if (tab0 != null) {
                        tab0.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_profile_unselected);
                        tab0.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab0TextUnSelected));
                    }

                    if (tab1 != null) {
                        tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_rewards_unselected);
                        tab1.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab1TextUnSelected));
                    }

                    if (tab2 != null) {
                        tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_gallups_unselected);
                        tab2.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab2TextUnSelected));
                    }

                    if (tab3 != null) {
                        tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_statistics_unselected);
                        tab3.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab3TextUnSelected));
                    }

                    if (tab4 != null) {
                        tab4.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_settings_unselected);
                        tab4.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab4TextUnSelected));
                    }

                    if (position == 0) {
                        if (tab0 != null) {
                            tab0.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_profile_selected);
                            tab0.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab0TextSelected));
                        }
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        if (tab1 != null) {
                            tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_rewards_selected);
                            tab1.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab1TextSelected));
                        }
                    } else if (position == 2) {
                        if (tab2 != null) {
                            tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_gallups_selected);
                            tab2.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab2TextSelected));
                        }
                    } else if (position == 3) {
                        if (tab3 != null) {
                            tab3.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_statistics_selected);
                            tab3.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab3TextSelected));
                        }
                    } else if (position == 4) {
                        if (tab4 != null) {
                            tab4.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_settings_selected);
                            tab4.setText(Html.fromHtml(tab4TextSelected));
                        }
                    }

                }


            });
```

I have override the `onBackPressed` method as follow

```
 if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
     mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true);
}
```

To sum up, I have tabs with icons and texts. When a tab is selected then the icon is changed and the text turned in green color. When a tab is unselected then the icon is changed and the text turned in white color. This worked fine when the user clicks on tabs. When the user clicks on back button then the icon and the text color are changed correctly but for the previous tab the text remains on green color.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1,false);
        }else{
             finish();
        }

    }
```

but do not call super.onBackPressed() method.

Comment: the second param is for the smooth scroll.. Anyway I tested and OMG it worked

Comment: @Pradeep Gupta could you explain the reason why?

Comment: if you disable the smooth scroll (the second parameter), then it will go directly to the page you want with no scroll motion (and will not "change" to the other pages on the way), and if you enable the smooth scroll then it will go through all the views, so you will see how it was not the next one but the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Override `onBackPressed()` method of your `Activity` with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int currentItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    if (currentItem != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentItem - 1, true);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No sure if I understood your problem correctly, but try to call

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

after you `if` statement.

Comment: If I use super.onBackPressed() it closes my activity.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewPager needs an OnPageChangeListener to change the selected Tab.

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
        new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between pages, select the
                // corresponding tab.
                getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
...
```

Comment: setOnPageChangeListener is deprecated

Comment: and also my app crashes

Comment: use addOnPageChangeListener instead then.

Comment: I have already use addOnPageChangeListener and I have override the onTabSelected & onTabUnselected but doesn't work